# what is bits per sample Structure of .wav Audio Files

Tags: audio, byte, wav, pcm, bitrate

in the example of this post

http://dracoater.blogspot.com/2008/11/comparing-2-audio-wav-files.html

bits per sample is 0010 or 16 (in DEC)
but why each sample contains 4 bytes ? 
4 X 8 = 32 bits !?

[image]

Comment: its showing stereo which is 2 channels (left + right),  each channel is 16 bits

Answer (score 1):

Each of those "samples" labeled on the bottom line of your diagram is actually 2 samples - i.e. each circled pair of 2 bytes is a sample - The diagram is wrong.

If it's a stereo file, the samples will be in pairs (one for left, one for right) - that group is usually called a "frame". The sample channels are interleaved in the file e.g. LRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLR